# Error ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized. in C# script SSIS

Tags: c#

I am getting the error in this code block and can not seem to find the issue.

```
SqlConnection con = (SqlConnection)(Dts.Connections["connection"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as SqlConnection);
ssqlRiskQuery = "My query";

using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(ssqlRiskQuery, con))
{
    command.Connection = con;
    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            OutputFileObjects.Add(reader["p.provider_id"].ToString(), new string[] { reader["bu.business_unit_id"].ToString(), reader["l.location_id"].ToString(), reader["cpd.claim_number"].ToString(), reader["v2.process_code"].ToString() });
        }
    }
}
con.Close();
```

Comment: youre not calling con.Open()

Comment: Yes, the Open is missing, but the error message points to the SqlConnection being null. I bet if she calls _con.Open()_ a NRE is raised

Comment: It would be more clear if you add the code of _AquireConnection_

Comment: If i open the connection it gives me Null object reference error

Comment: As expected. NRE comes out from the fact that AcquireConnection doesn't return an SqlConnection and your cast result in a null assigned to the variable con. When you call con.Open is a NRE, if you don't call the Open then ExecuteReader has no valid connection to use. So, again, the problem is inside the code of AcquireConnection. Check it or add this code to your question

Comment: @Steve Which code?

Comment: I thought that was your code but now I understand that you are using this class [ConnectionManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.connectionmanager.aspx). Well, in any case I would check if the con variable is null and then, if it is null, try to discover why the call to AcquireConnection fails. Perhaps there is no entry in the Dts.Connections named "connection"

Answer (score 0):

You need `connection.Open();`

You haven't opened the connection.